# Getting has_many through models using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently getting **has_many** relationship associations of a **User** model using this

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

Now, how can I want to get **User** models with **has_many through** associations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want the `has_many :through` associations, you can filter your array like this:

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).select do |association|
  association.options.key? :through
end
```